# How to calculate the sum of multiple rows of a single column in mysql

Tags: mysql

Below is my code i am trying to calculate the sum of values in a single column that is: SUM(sum) as total, which i want to print in the  of my output table as Total; but that part of the code is not producing the expected output.

```
<?php
require_once('includes/connect.php');
$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT studentid, hw1, hw2, hw3, SUM(hw1+hw2+hw3) as sum, SUM(sum) as total FROM scores GROUP BY studentid");

echo "<table border='1'>
<thead>
<tr>
    <th>StudentID</th>
    <th>HW1</th>
    <th>HW2</th>
    <th>HW3</th>
    <th>SUM</th>
</tr>
</thead>";

echo "<tfoot>
<tr>
    <td>Total:</td>
    <td> echo SUM(sum);</td>
</tr>
</tfoot>";
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
"<tbody>
  <tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['studentid'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['hw1'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['hw2'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['hw3'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['sum'] . "</td>";
    echo "
  </tr>
 </tbody>"; 
}
 echo "</table>";

 mysqli_close($con);
 ?>
```

I shall appreciate suggestions to resolve this.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is wrong in your query `SUM(sum) as total`

```
$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT studentid, hw1, hw2, hw3, SUM(hw1+hw2+hw3) as sum, SUM(sum) as total FROM scores GROUP BY studentid");
```

Should be like this

```
$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT studentid, hw1, hw2, hw3, SUM(hw1+hw2+hw3) as sum FROM scores GROUP BY studentid");
```

Comment: The "SUM(hw1+hw2+hw3) as sum" statement is the sum of the three columns h1, h2 and h3, in addition to that, i also want to find the total of each sum row along a single column, that is why i have this second statement "SUM(sum) as total".

Answer (score 0):

If the values could be `NULL` and you want to *ignore* those values, then you might want:

```
SELECT studentid, hw1, hw2, hw3,
       (coalesce(sum(hw1), 0) + coalesce(sum(hw2), 0) +coalesce(sum(hw3), 0)) as total
FROM scores
GROUP BY studentid;
```